# Fringe Modes of Governance?

Tags: political-philosophy

Back in the days of the ancient Greeks, the dominant form of rule was hereditary autocracy. The “fringe” or “cutting edge” theory was democracy. This happened again during the Renaissance, and again during the political revolutions of the nineteenth century.

Is there any modern version of a “cutting edge” philosophy of governance?

Comment: Maybe fringe theories reject the government at all replacing it by something else?

Answer (score 2):

1. E-democracy: It's one of the pledges of the Italian party “MoVimento 5 Stelle” (“Five Star Movement”) and would be considered pretty fringe; but in the end, it's still just a *special* variant of democracy.
2. One could imagine a future in which decentralized, self-organizing, non-state *systems* have progressively siphoned away all sovereign rights from the state (e.g. a cryptocurrency could eliminate monetary sovereignty) – yet it's difficult to extrapolate this beyond the few examples we already know today. On the face of it, this sounds like anarchism, but the difference would be that people could really *trust* the “system”: the system would provide stability and also be able to defend itself against power grabs from centralized actors.
3. automatic governance; artificial intelligence makes government decisions. A subject of (usually dystopian) Sci-Fi novels. The fringest one of the three examples. Yet today, if a problem can't be fully formalized, AIs tend to behave strangely. They [can be tricked](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/machine-learning-is-fun-part-8-how-to-intentionally-trick-neural-networks-b55da32b7196) and sometimes make extremely bizarre errors. It's a matter of faith to believe, that what AI does remotely resembles the operations of the human mind, or, that AI (on the basis of a digital computer) will ever be able to cope with general concepts.

Comment: Who are the authors of last two? Or where have you even took them?

Comment: I synthesized a lot of stuff, there's no single person who came up with them. Regarding 2.) you can read *Disruptive Power: The Crisis of the State in the Digital Age* by Taylor Owen. Regarding 3.) Steven James Bartlett has seriously entertained this idea.

Comment: I recommend Charles Stross's "Glasshouse." He has an interesting theory of self-propagating polity structures.